# Can Trap Hole be activated in response to Denko Sekka's summon?

Tags: yu-gi-oh

[Trap Hole](https://yugioh.fandom.com/wiki/Trap_Hole) is a normal trap card (speed 2), and normal summon of [Denko Sekka](https://yugioh.fandom.com/wiki/Denko_Sekka) (speed 1). Trap hole (as I believe) is faster but doesn't include summon negation (it only destroys). I've read in some forums people saying you can only activate cards that has negation effect like Solemn Warning.

So my question can we activate Trap Hole against Denko Sekka?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> So my question can we activate Trap Hole against Denko Sekka?

**No.**

The reason is because [Trap Hole](https://yugioh.fandom.com/wiki/Trap_Hole) effect activates *after* the summoning of [Denko Sekka](https://yugioh.fandom.com/wiki/Denko_Sekka), thus her effect is already in place. This is exactly the reason why Denko Sekka's effect is powerful.

Reading Trap Hole's effect, emphasis mine:

> **When** *[that is after the summon is successful]* your opponent Normal or Flip Summons 1 monster with 1000 or more ATK: Target that monster; destroy that target.

You could, however, *negate* and prevent her summoning altogether, with cards like [Solemn Warning](https://yugioh.fandom.com/wiki/Solemn_Warning) as you correctly pointed out. From its text, emphasis mine:

> **When a monster(s) would be Summoned**, OR when a Spell/Trap Card, or monster effect, is activated that includes an effect that Special Summons a monster(s): Pay 2000 LP; **negate the Summon** or activation, and if you do, destroy that card.

Comment: As you highlighted from Solemn Warning: "When a monster(s) **would be** summoned.."! Your answer is an enlightment!

Comment: Glad I could help. Indeed, the "would be" is key here: the summon has not happened yet.